# Select maximum value where another column is used for for the Grouping

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to join several tables, where one of the tables is acting as a
key-value store, and then after the joins find the maximum value in a
column less than another column. As a simplified example, I have the following three tables:

Documents:

| DocumentID | Filename | LatestRevision |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | D1001.SLDDRW | 18 |
| 2 | P5002.SLDPRT | 10 |

Variables:

| VariableID | VariableName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | DateReleased |
| 2 | Change |
| 3 | Description |

VariableValues:

| DocumentID | VariableID | Revision | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | Created |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | Drawing |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | Changed Dimension |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 2021-02-01 |
| 1 | 2 | 11 | Corrected typos |
| 1 | 1 | 16 | 2021-02-25 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | Generic part |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | Screw |
| 2 | 2 | 4 | 2021-02-24 |

I can use the `LEFT JOIN`/`IS NULL` thing to get the latest version of
variables relatively easily (see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/5982d/3/0).

What I want is the latest version of variables that are less than or equal
to a revision which has a DateReleased, for example:

| DocumentID | Filename | Variable | Value | VariableRev | DateReleased | ReleasedRev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | D1001.SLDDRW | Change | Changed Dimension | 3 | 2021-02-01 | 4 |
| 1 | D1001.SLDDRW | Description | Drawing | 1 | 2021-02-01 | 4 |
| 1 | D1001.SLDDRW | Description | Drawing | 1 | 2021-02-25 | 16 |
| 1 | D1001.SLDDRW | Change | Corrected Typos | 11 | 2021-02-25 | 16 |
| 2 | P5002.SLDPRT | Description | Generic Part | 1 | 2021-02-24 | 4 |

How do I do this?

Comment: Your question is too dense and lacks critical information such as the schemas you are joining.

Comment: Completely re-written - does this clarify what I mean well enough?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Add another `JOIN` at the start to add in another version of the VariableValues table selecting only the DateReleased variables, then make sure that all the VariableValues Revisions selected are less than this date released. I think the `LEFT JOIN` has to be added after this table.

The example at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd6068/3/0 shows this better.